# Failed container creation: LXD doesn't have a uid/gid allocation

Tags: lxd

I'm trying to lauch an lxd container, but I get this:

```
lxc launch ubuntu:16.04
A criar o contentor
Error: Failed container creation: LXD doesn't have a uid/gid allocation. In this mode, only privileged containers are supported
```

I get this (relevant part) with cat /var/log/lxd/lxd.log

```
lvl=info msg="LXD 3.0.2 is starting in normal mode" path=/var/lib/lxd t=2018-11-10T13:42:30+0000
err="User \"root\" has no subuids" lvl=warn msg="Error reading default uid/gid map" t=2018-11-10T13:42:30+0000
lvl=warn msg="Only privileged containers will be able to run" t=2018-11-10T13:42:30+0000
```

...

Any ideas on how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

With the help of dnegreira on freenode #lxcontainers, it was all a question of editing /etc/subuid and /etc/subgid and adding

```
root:1000000:65536
```

to those files.

Comment: Hi, you should also add `lxd:1000000:65536`, as [they should always be in sync](https://ubuntu.com/blog/custom-user-mappings-in-lxd-containers). Remember to restart lxd after `systemctl restart lxd`